# Giving a JsPlumb Connection an invisible border

Tags: jsplumb

I've been running into an issue with clicking on JsPlumb connections. In my application, users can draw connections between JsPlumb objects, and delete them by clicking on a connection and confirming on a deletion prompt.

The specific issue that I'm having is that the connections are too thin to be able to click on easily (especially on mobile devices, for which this application is also targeted), and yet for design reasons, the width of these connections cannot be enlarged.

The solution I'm looking into is creating a sort of invisible buffer around each connection, to give the user a bit of leeway in selecting them. However, I've been looking into how I might do this, and I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Here's my JsPlumb defaults:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
    Anchors: [
        ["Perimeter", {
            shape: "Rectangle"
        }],
        ["Perimeter", {
            shape: "Rectangle"
        }]
    ],
    Connector: ["Straight"],
    ConnectionsDetachable: false,
    ConnectionOverlays: [
        ["Arrow", {
            width: 8,
            length: 15,
            location: 1
        }],
        ["Label", {
            label: '0',
            id: "distanceLabel",
            cssClass: "distance-label"
        }]
    ],
    DoNotThrowErrors: false
});
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not looking to add elements on top of the connections, as I still want to use the JsPlumb `click` event to handle deletions. If anyone has any ideas how this could be done, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From API's I couldn't find any option for setting border for connections. Try connection labels  as work around solution. Connection will be removed when user clicks on the label.

[**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/px087agp/2/)

You can set label in defaults as:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
   ConnectionOverlays: [["Label", {
      cssClass:"component",
      label : "<div class='DCon'><div>",
      location:0.4,
      id:"label",
      events:{
        "click": function(label, evt) {
           jsPlumb.detach(label.component);
        },
        "mouseenter": function(label, evt) {
           label.component.setPaintStyle({lineWidth:1,strokeStyle:"#FF0040"});
        },
        "mouseexit": function(label, evt) { // Try "mouseleave" if this doesn't work.
           label.component.setPaintStyle({lineWidth:1,strokeStyle:"gray"});
        }
      }
   }]
});
```

I have specified the label image in the CSS:

```
.DCon {
   background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTk2D-dANCTuefhUI8C9Q3krWq5-J0tZpeSPY65Qc6bUuZLz1Uj);
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   cursor:pointer;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set an invisible outline (with alpha = 0) to each connector:

```
PaintStyle:
{
    outlineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    outlineWidth:10
}
```

References:

- https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/paint-styles.html
- https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/defaults.html